# Execução não bloqueante com funções assíncronas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async

Eu quero que um certo fluxo continue mesmo chamando um `async.sleep()` no código, tenho seguinte código

```py
import asyncio

async def funcao_1(name):
    print("entrando no sono...")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("saindo do sono...")

async def main():
    result = await asyncio.gather(funcao_1())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(main())
print("rodando depois do run_until_complete")
```

**Saída esperada**

```
entrando no sono...
rodando depois do run_until_complete
saindo do sono...
```

**Saída retornada**

```
entrando no sono...
saindo do sono...
rodando depois do run_until_complete
```

**Versão do Python**

```bsh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.7rc1
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso em Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para rodar duas tarefas concorrentemente, utilize a função `async.gather`.

Exemplo:

```py
import asyncio

async def funcao1():
    print('entrando no sono...')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('saindo do sono...')

async def funcao2():
    print('rodando de forma independente!')

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(funcao1(), funcao2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Se a versão do seu Python for menor que 3.7, use o seguinte:
    #
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(main())

    asyncio.run(main())
```

Saída no terminal:

```
entrando no sono...
rodando de forma independente!
saindo do sono...
```

Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

Comment: existe uma outra maneira sem usar a função `gather`? tipo na minha proposta inicial de rodar uma execução depois do `run_until_complete(main())` ou `asyncio.run(main())`

Comment: @DaviWesley Os códigos que serão executados concorrentemente devem ser marcados como `async`, por isso eu criei duas funções separadas e as marquei com `async`. Se o código não for marcado como `async`, o event loop não tem como controlar a execução e, portanto, não tem como ser concorrente. Se você não quiser usar o event loop por alguma razão, terá que usar threads diretamente, mas eu recomendo usar somente o `async`, pois o resultado final fica mais expressivo e simples do que usando threads diretamente.